# Time complexity from pseudocode

Tags: time-complexity

I am trying to find the Time complexity from the lines of code. However, I am not really getting it.

```
int codeMT(int n) {
    int a = 1;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < n * n) {
     j = 1;
      while (j < n * n * n) {
       j = j * 3;
       a = a + j + i;
     }
   i = i + 2;
   }
  return a;
}
```

In this case, this is my thought process.

Firstly, we need to start from the inner loop.

```
while (j < n * n * n) {
           j = j * 3;
           a = a + j + i;
         }
```

In here, there is j = j * 3 which makes this log(n)(log base 3) but then we have a loop guard that has n*n*n which makes the n^3. Therefore, this part of code has log(n^3) time complexity.

Secondly, the outer while loop has the loop guard of n * n which makes it n^2.

Thus, O(n^2(log(n^3))

Is my approach okay? or is there anything that I am missing/things that I could improve my thought process?

Thank you

Comment: log(n^3) = 3 log(n) which is O(log(n)), so you can simplify a bit.

Comment: I see, I think I understood. So, the n^2 part was right but then, I need to change the log(n^3) = 3log(n) and constant drops thus, = log(n). So, n^2 * log(n) = n^2log(n). Thank you!